# Calling WordApplication.Open with VB6 fails when running as local User

Tags: iis, automation, ms-word, vb6, admin

I'm running a DLL file that is referenced by an "xpto.asp" file.
At some point of the code, this DLL opens a word template file:

```
  set oWordApp=New Word.Application
  set oWordDoc= oWordApp.Documents.Open(sTemplate,,true)
```

In IIS i´m using  `User Authentication(pass throught)` authentication.

This code works fine if the login user has ADMIN privileges.

If the login user doesn't have ADMIN privileges then an Error occurs when tryng to open the template:

> Automation error   The remote procedure call failed. (error.number
>   =2147023170)

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: A search here might shed some light on this. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+remote+procedure+call+failed.+0x800706BE

Comment: Have you tried to grant permission in DCOM? It sounds like your authenticated user don't have permission to access the component.

Comment: Also check Microsoft Office folder and subfolders permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments (@KenWhite). I found the answer in your comment link.  The answer was in this response [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579209/the-remote-procedure-call-failed-excel-inside-iis). the permissions for DCOM ,word folders etc where fine. What i was missing was selecting  Interactive user in Identity Tab . After that it Worked!!! by the way, anyone knows why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The remote procedure call failed Excel inside IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579209/the-remote-procedure-call-failed-excel-inside-iis)

Comment: Hi Nuno. Since you're new to the site a couple of explanations/pointers: 1) When you find an answer (or question) you consider helpful, please click the up-arrow at its left. This helps with site quality - it tells others when people find the information useful...

Comment: 2) Since this is a Q&A site, when an Answer is found to apply to other questions we mark those later questions as "duplicates". Depending on the search terms used, other questions than the one with "the answer" may be turned up. This leads the people to the answer, when they click the "duplicate" link. It's more efficient than answers "all over the place" :-) That's why I've "flagged" your question as a duplicate (and that first comment with my name on it is a site automation).